# SKScene bounds and positioning

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, positioning, skscene

I'm trying my best to use my "responsive" / "adaptive" knowledge to apply it to positioning in my `SKScene`.

However, it would appear there's a problem. As the width / height of the scene aren't accurate.

In this example, the view's anchor point is centerpoint i.e 0.5, 0.5.

```
    SKLabelNode *label = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithText:@"Welcome to the table..."];
    label.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
    label.alpha = 0;
    [self addChild:label];
```

now let's say, I want to move that to the bottom of the screen. I use the screen sizing logic so I can apply it for every device.

`label.position = CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.height/2 + label.frame.height);`

From what I can see, it should align the X to the anchor point, then deduct y from the anchor point.  So CenterPoint - half screen height + label height.. However, this isn't the case. It's offscreen somewhere not working accurately.

I've also tried this with `self.frame.size.height` & `self.view.bounds.size.height`

Comment: Just for info...if you didn't already know. Instead of finding centerY by writing `view.frame.height/2` you can use the helper method `CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)`. There's also `CGRectGetMidX(), CGRectGetMinX(), CGRectGetMaxX(), CGRectGetMinY() and CGRectGetMaxY()`

Comment: Or, you could use the `midX` and `midY` properties on `CGRect`, as well as `minX`, `maxX`, `minY` and `maxY`. They do the same things as the functions suggested by @pbods. However using properties, IMO, is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the size of your `SKScene` doesn't match the size of its `SKView`. Try setting the `scaleMode` of your scene to `ResizeFill`. From the [`SKScene` documentation on `ResizeFill`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SKSceneScaleMode):

> The scene is not scaled to match the view. Instead, the scene is automatically resized so that its dimensions always match those of the view.